# Google Play Service stopped on Android

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have face a problem with my Samsung Galaxy Note after an update of Google Play Service that I can't access to Google Play. Then I try to uninstall the latest update of Google Play Service from application manager.

But, after that, I also unable to access any Google account related services from my device like, Google+, Google Search etc.

How, can I repair my device to access all Google service properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simple try the following process:

```
settings --> application manager --> all --> click the bottom left touch button and select reset apps
```

Its work perfectly for me.

Now I can download app from Google Play, and also can access any Google account related services like Google+, Google Maps etc.

Hope, it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try to clear data of "Google Play Store" you can also do following option like
Disable play store and then enable again.
Force stop play store then try to open it

Have you try to restart your phone? May it will also helpful you.

Comment: Restarting my device does not help me.

Comment: I don't try to clear data of play service, but, I try with disabling the application, and it does not work too.

Answer (score 0):

This method works only if you are rooted and have `Clockworkmode` recovery.
Follow these steps:

1. Uninstall Google play services.
2. Boot into recovery and select wipe data.
3. Then select clear cache.
4. Then select advance and in it select delvik cache.
5. Then go back and select reboot.

All Done!!

Now the Google play store will start working.